# MySQL Join and find in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I know there alot of Questions regarding this matter, however i cant make sense as they seem to be direct answers with no great understanding to me.

This is what I want to do:

I have three tables: `fusers`, `tusers`, `lusers`. They
all contain the row: `email`

I want to combine the three tables, and find out if a user submitted variable `$email` already exists in the `email` row.

I know that using inner joins and possibly union all will work, but for the life of me, i can't find a decent tutorial or example which i can learn from.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT some_primary_id as id, 'fusers' as table_name FROM fusers WHERE email = '$email' UNION 
SELECT some_other_primary_id as id, 'tusers' as table_name FROM tusers WHERE email = '$email' UNION
SELECT some_misc_primary_id as id, 'lusers' as table_name FROM lusers WHERE email = '$email'
```

Notice I used `fusers_id as id`, because all columns in union selects need to have the same name

Thanks to @njk you may use `UNION ALL` which will be faster as `UNION` alone is checking for duplicate rows and removes them.

**Syntax:**

```
(SELECT a as COMMON_COLUMN_1, b as COMMON_COLUMN_2, c as COMMON_COLUMN3 FROM xxx WHERE ...)
UNION
(SELECT d as COMMON_COLUMN_1, e as COMMON_COLUMN_2, f as COMMON_COLUMN3 FROM yyy WHERE ...)
UNION
(SELECT g as COMMON_COLUMN_1, h as COMMON_COLUMN_2, i as COMMON_COLUMN3 FROM zzz WHERE ...)
# where a,b,c are columns from table xxx ONLY
# where d,e,f are columns from table yyy ONLY
# where g,h,j are columns from table zzz ONLY
```

- Docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

**Simply `UNION` is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set.**

Comment: can you explain what this is doing, in layman terms. I think i understand some. shouldnt `fusers_id` be `fusers.id`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Edited my answer. @njk hmm no need as I am adding table name `'fusers' as table_name` to every row

Comment: Actually, there is. `UNION ALL` is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select if(count(*) > 0, 1, 0) as exists from fusers f, tusers t, lusers l where f.email = "$email" or t.email = "$email" or l.email = "$email";
```

Comment: This will return 1 when email exists in one of those tables, and 0 when it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

> I have three tables: fusers, tusers, lusers. They all contain the row: email
>
> I want to combine the three tables, and find out if a user submitted variable $email already exists in the email row.

You have three tables describing users which have common fields? Then the answer (as usual) is to normalize your data: all the common data should be in a single table.

Comment: that would mean me undertaking a massive operation as these tables a huge. simply searching through to find the variable is easier. for me.

Comment: No - it's a trivial operation - and you can preserve the functionality of existing code by using views.